# Xcode 7 no internet available error after updating

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

**hello guys**

i have developed an app on xcode 6.4, it was working fine. after updating to xcode 7, i get the no internet connection available. the safari in the simulator is working however the app isn't recieving any connection

so i tried to go back to xcode 6.4 and thought of publishing my app to itunesconnect through it, but i get embedded.mobileprovision error, even though its there.

im basically stuck atm

**Device information:**

Macbook pro 
osx 10.0
xcode 7 and 6.4

**any suggestions?**

Comment: Have you tried setting keys for NSAppTransportSecurity ?

Comment: App Transport Security

Comment: yes thank you it worked!